# JSON-LD / Hydra Console - Entry Point seems not to be correct

Tags: entry-point, json-ld, hydra-core

please forgive me this probably very stupid question, but I do not understand how to resolve my problem on my own.
I discovered the Hydra Console from M. Lanthaler and deployed it to my own Machine (apache2). I then tried to create an entry point similar to the one in the Example Application (Issue Tracker) used as an example for the Hydra Console.
It looks like this:

```
{
    "@context": "EntryPoint.jsonld",
    "@id": "index.jsonld",
    "@type": "EntryPoint",
    "issues": "example/issues.jsonld"
}
```

The Context and Vocab are deployed to the same directory as EntryPoint.jsonld.
Unfortunately, this does not work. If I open this document in the Hydra Console, it looks like this:

```
{
   "@context": ,
   "@id": ,
   "@type": ,
  "issues": 
}
```

And it says "not mapped to an IRI" as a tooltip on the later three. As there is no error message or any way for me to understand what is wrong I ask the question here. Please help me to solve the problem. If you have hints for me how to debug on my own that would be welcomed.

(Note: I tried to use the JSON-LD playground, but it is not of much help as it cannot load the JSONLD stuff from Lanthaler's Website either.)

Answer (score 0):

The [HydraConsole](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/) uses a bit of server-side PHP processing to retrieve and render JSON-LD responses. I assume you set up PHP properly to allow it to make HTTP requests. Did you update EntryPoint.jsonld to point to the right documents instead of my domain (the `vocab` mapping in that file points to markus-lanthaler.com)?

In general, the best venue to get help regarding JSON-LD/Hydra is the mailing list of the Hydra W3C Community Group. Join the group and post your questions to the list: http://www.hydra-cg.com/#community

Comment: I am getting a similar issue, both on the public site and my own instance.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296806/json-hydra-console-not-detecting-properly
Kind of disappointing, considering I am on a timeframe -_-