# JSON Hydra Console not detecting properly

Tags: json-ld, hydra-core

I have recently just started experimenting with the Hydra Console. Looks to me as it is broken.

If you navigate to the public version: http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/console/#

and enter this URL: `http://kadebom.com/EntryPoint.jsonld` (which is an exact copy of [the example](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/contexts/EntryPoint.jsonld), except on my server)

it just returns `"@context":` and doesn't have any values present.

Please see the screenshot:

> [image: Screenshof Hydra Console output, showing only '{ "@context": }']

There are no errors in the JS console. I tried changing my Apache config to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` but to no avail.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your document doesn't seem to be an exact copy (anymore, I assume after reading your own answer). Put an exact copy of [the example](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/contexts/EntryPoint.jsonld) there and make sure to serve it with the right content type, i.e., `Content-Type: application/ld+json`.

If you want the documentation on the right hand side to show up as well, you also need to reference the ApiDocumentation from a `Link` header as the example does (do a `curl -i http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/contexts/EntryPoint.jsonld` to see how the demo does it.

Btw. I would suggest you to look at the [Event API Demo](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/console/?url=http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/event-api/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, unspecified in any documentation, and please, if there is some, please provide it, my json document had to be:

```
{
"@context": {
    "__value": "/hydra/api-demo/contexts/EntryPoint.jsonld",
    "__activectx": {
        "@base": {},
        "hydra": {
            "@id": "http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#",
            "@reverse": false
        },
        "vocab": {
            "@id": "http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/vocab#",
            "@reverse": false
        },
        "EntryPoint": {
            "@id": "http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/vocab#EntryPoint",
            "@reverse": false
        },
        "issues": {
            "@id": "http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/vocab#EntryPoint/issues",
            "@reverse": false,
            "@type": "@id"
        },
        "register_user": {
            "@id": "http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/vocab#EntryPoint/registerUser",
            "@reverse": false,
            "@type": "@id"
        },
        "my_account": {
            "@id": "http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/vocab#EntryPoint/myAccount",
            "@reverse": false,
            "@type": "@id"
        },
        "users": {
            "@id": "http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/vocab#EntryPoint/users",
            "@reverse": false,
            "@type": "@id"
        }
    }
},
"@id": {
    "__iri": "@id",
    "__value": {
        "__orig_value": "/hydra/api-demo/",
        "__value": {
            "@id": "http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/"
        }
    }
},
"@type": {
    "__iri": "@type",
    "__value": {
        "__orig_value": "EntryPoint",
        "__value": {
            "@id": "http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/vocab#EntryPoint"
        }
    }
},
"issues": {
    "__iri": "http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/vocab#EntryPoint/issues",
    "__value": {
        "__orig_value": "/hydra/api-demo/issues/",
        "__value": {
            "@id": "http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/issues/"
        }
    }
},
"register_user": {
    "__iri": "http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/vocab#EntryPoint/registerUser",
    "__value": {
        "__orig_value": "/hydra/api-demo/users/",
        "__value": {
            "@id": "http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/users/"
        }
    }
},
"users": {
    "__iri": "http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/vocab#EntryPoint/users",
    "__value": {
        "__orig_value": "/hydra/api-demo/users/",
        "__value": {
            "@id": "http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/users/"
        }
    }
}
```

}

rather than what will be downloaded if you go to this url:

```
http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/event-api/
```